# Store result of every line processed in database- Spring batch

Tags: csv, spring-batch, jobs

I want to use Spring Batch for CSV Parsing-> do some processing -> store result of job in db:
For every line in CSV it should do following :

```
1) Read line of CSV file
2) parse it
3) use the parsed tokens to do some processing
4) Store the result(success/failure with reason) of this processing in database.
```

I am new to Spring-Batch. I saw some examples on line. But i did not see results stored line by line. Could anyone please guide me whether this is possible in Spring batch?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need to use spring batch really for this case, because only advantage is that item reader configuration to parse the csv file. I would rather prefer supercsv to read the file, process it and then commit status to database at the end. Anyways in spring batch you achieve it by using item reader to read the data from csv file, use the item processor to process the file and at the end of the processor call a DB call. Spring batch stores execution status of each step and job, not sure you can get the status of each line. you can check with chunk listener.

Comment: Thanks. This is just one of the benefits of Spring Batch that I will be using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring batch reads line by line and processes line by line. However, to optimize the writing we write all of the chunk at once.  If you want to process your file line by line, committing (and therefore writing) each line one at a time, all you need to do is change the commit-interval to 1.

You can read more about how to get started using Spring Batch with this Getting Started Guide from Spring: http://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/